# How to handle with csrf-protecting in Django views?

Tags: python, django, django-csrf

Hello and thank your for your response.

1) I have a model with **text** and **digit**

```
class Mention(models.Model):
    mentionn = models.ForeignKey(Step, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    mention_text = models.TextField()
    mention_digit = models.IntegerField()
```

2) A made custom from (not a django, so it is without any modelForm and so on), which request **text** and **digit**

```
<form action="/addcomment{{ stepid }}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<label>
Your text
<textarea name = "mention_text" class="text-area-width" placeholder="You rваш отзыв"></textarea>
</label>
    <label>How much stars?
        <select name="mention_digit">
            <option value="5">5 star</option>
            <option value="4">4 star</option>
            <option value="3">3 star</option>
            <option value="2">2 star</option>
            <option value="1">1 star</option>
        </select>
        </label>
    <input type="submit" class="success expanded button" value="publish"/>
</form>
```

3) Next i made an view, that genetate it:

```
def addcomment(request, step_id):
    done = csrf(request)
    if request.POST:
       mentionn = Step(id=step_id)
       mention_text = request.POST.get('mention_text', '')
        mention_digit = request.POST.get('mention_digit', '')
        mentionn_obj = Mention(mentionn=mentionn, mention_text=mention_text, mention_digit=mention_digit)
        mentionn_obj.save()        
    return redirect('/step'+ step_id, done)
```

And it raise a problem, that csrf_token missing or incorrect. If i set a @csrf_exempt decorator on my view eveything is works (but protection is switched off).

So my task is to make it works. I don't want use django forms, as it is rather harde to cusomize and make look nice.

---

Global model for web-page:

```
class Step(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    annotation = models.TextField()
    main_text = models.TextField()
    main_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='', height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=100)
    true_question = models.TextField()
    true_answer = models.TextField()
    true_link = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="http://lieman.ru/exshelp/")
```

View, that generate all page:

```
def step(request, step_id):
    stepfields = get_object_or_404(Step, id = step_id)
    navigators = Navigation_bar.objects.filter(navigatorr_id = step_id)
    mentionship = Mention.objects.filter(mentionn_id = step_id)
    username = auth.get_user(request).username
    stepid = step_id
    context = {
        "stepfieldst" : stepfields,
        "navigators" : navigators,
        "mentionship" : mentionship,
        "stepid" : stepid,
        "username" : username,
    }
    return render_to_response('bakot/step.html', context)
```

Comment: Can you add in the traceback of the error and your `views.py`?

Comment: What does `csrf` function in your view do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To [enable CSRF protection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/csrf/#how-to-use-it), you need to include the request whenever you render a template that uses the `{% csrf_token %}` tag.

At the moment, you are not doing this for your `step` view. The easiest way to do this is to use `render` instead of `render_to_response`.

```
return render(request, 'bakot/step.html', context)
```

It's not clear what `make = csrf(request)` is meant to do in your `add_comment` view, but I don't think it's required.

Comment: I have updated my question. This is all files, i use to make my form works.

Comment: Which view renders the template that displays the form? It can't be the `add_comment` view, because all that does is redirect the user.

Comment: Add information about global model and it's view, that generate all page.

Comment: The problem is in your `step` view. See my updated answer.

Comment: Yes, it works, thank you!

Idefinetely should learn difference beetween render(request) and render_to_response

Comment: If you always use `render` instead of `render_to_response` then you won't have any problems.